# DeprecationWarning in scikit-learn while using pos_label

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am getting the following warning when I run my code

```
DeprecationWarning: From version 0.18, binary input will not be handled 
specially when using averaged precision/recall/F-score. Please use  
average='binary' to report only the positive class performance.
'positive class performance.', DeprecationWarning
```

Here's my code

```
splits = StratifiedShuffleSplit(labels, n_iter = 5, test_size = 0.2)
if(condition):
    scorefunc = make_scorer(fbeta_score, beta = 1, pos_label = labels[0]) 
else:
    scorefunc = make_scorer(fbeta_score, beta = 1, pos_label = None)

params1 = {'penalty':['l1'],'C':[0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1.0]}
lr = GridSearchCV(LogisticRegression(), param_grid = params1, cv = splits, n_jobs = 5, scoring = scorefunc)
lr.fit(matrix, labels)
```

I am suspecting that this has something to do with how I am handling the pos_label parameter, but reading the documentation I could not figure out what it is that I am doing wrong. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: What is `labels` in `pos_label=labels`? It seems that you are using average method other than `'binary'` but I find no clues from your code.

Comment: @yangjie thanks for your help. sorry, I had pasted slightly different version of the code. I have edited it now. Yes, the default [averaging in f1](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html) is 'binary'. The labels could be binary or multi-class depending on what happens earlier in the program.

Comment: This is weird - according to the source (sklearn/metrics/classification.py#L573) this warning should only appear if average != binary and pos_label is not None. In the code above you are using the default average, which is always set to binary. So this warning should not appear at all.